# How do I change SearchView/ActionBar colors in styles?

Tags: android

Usually, I want my ActionBar color to NOT be colorPrimary (which for my app is a dark blue) but instead match the window background, a light grey, just like [this](https://www.iphonefaq.org/images/archives/app-google-calendar-free.jpg)

The text should be almost black, and the shadow should still be there. How do I go about accomplishing this in an Object oriented way? (I dont want to manually/programmatically set each field for the action bar in onCreate())

Another thing is, I'm making a SearchView take up the entire action bar, like [this](https://i0.wp.com/www.instinctcoder.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/AS_SearchWidget_07.jpg)

I want the background in this case to be completely white, both the icons and text to be dark grey/black, how to do that?

I want to add the X close icon in the SearchView above, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

header.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/back_icon"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.9"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Enter customer Mobile Number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp"></EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
             android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>



 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/dash_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
<style name="ColorTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">YOUR_COLOR_CODE</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` set your application/activity theme as `ColorTheme` like this

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme
```

inside your application/activity tag and add the code in styles